# Custom ActiveAdmin filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, arel, ransack

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I'm trying to implement my own filters.

1. Filter by day/week/month
2. Filter by price (virtual attribute), greater than and less than

**businesses.rb**

```
filter :period_eq, as: :select, collection: [['day', 'day'], ['week', 'week']]
filter :price_lteq, as: :string
filter :price_gteq, as: :string
```

**business.rb**

```
ransacker :period,
  formatter: -> period {
    from = {
      day: Time.now.beginning_of_day,
      week: 1.week.ago.beginning_of_day,
      month: 1.month.ago.beginning_of_day,
      year: 1.year.ago.beginning_of_day,
    }[period.to_sym]
    Business.where('updated_at >= ?', from).pluck(:id)
  }, splat_params: true do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
end
ransacker :price do |parent|
  # equivalent to Business.where('(owner_price + comission) >= ?', price)
end
```

I need 2 separate fields for price, not the ActiveAdmin default [lt, gt, eq] dropdown.

I couldn't figure, which Arel expression I should put in ransacker body?
And what are alternative solutions to my problem? I mean avoiding using ransack.

**UPDATE**
I managed to get :price filter working:

```
filter :price, as: :numeric_range

ransacker :price,
  formatter: -> price {
    price.to_s.gsub /[\u00A0\s]+/, ''
  }, splat_params: true do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('+',
      parent.table[:comission], parent.table[:owner_price])
end
```

But still need help with :period filter

Comment: have you tried specifying the `as` option for `price_lteq` and `price_gteq`?  I think it does a lookup on the model to see if a column/attribute exists for those or it ignores them.

Comment: @codenamev thanks, that worked. a followup question, can I create filter with 1 label and 2 input fields (from, to)? my code creates 2 filters with 2 labels.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to the answer ;-)

You have to specify the `as` option of the filter when the filter doesn't correspond to a column or attribute on the model:

```
filter :price_lteq, as: :string
```

If you're looking for a range, ActiveAdmin has `numeric_range`.  Try something like this:

```
filter :period, as: :select, collection: [['day', 'day'], ['week', 'week']]
filter :price, as: :numeric_range

ransacker :period, (period_name) -> {
  {
    day: Time.now.beginning_of_day,
    week: 1.week.ago.beginning_of_day,
    month: 1.month.ago.beginning_of_day,
    year: 1.year.ago.beginning_of_day,
  }[period.to_sym]
} do |parent|
  parent.table[:updated_at]
end

ransacker :price do |parent|
  formatter: -> price {
    price.to_s.gsub /[\u00A0\s]+/, ''
  }, splat_params: true do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('+', parent.table[:comission], parent.table[:owner_price])
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Figured numeric_range out. I didn't have it by default (probably old AA version), so added by creating new input type. Still the question is what do I write inside ransacker?

Comment: I get `undefined method `lteq' for "(owner_price + comission)"` for your solution. And ransacker :period with the code in my question doesn't work.

Comment: I managed to get :price working with `Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('+',
        parent.table[:comission], parent.table[:owner_price])`. Updated question. Can you help me with :period filter?